# ethzasl_sensor_fusion only works first time

Tags: ros, imu, sensor, ptam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Strangest thing happened at the end of completing the ethzasl_sensor_fusion getting started tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/ethzasl_sensor_fusion/Tutorials/getting_started

I followed the instructions and then ran the launch file. I see the graph working as expected (updated to rqt_plot). I then let the bag file run until it gets to the end. I'm thinking so far so good but then I try to run it again, now it won't work for me.

I have tried reinitialization everything again. I try over and over. The graph is now flat lining. I can't understand why it would only work once when nothing has changed.

The only thing that I can think of that may be different each time, is the time that I initialize the filter. This is always different as I stop the bag file after running it for approximately 1 second and then initialize as per instructions.

I either get an error warning:

`=== ERROR === update: NAN at index 0`

`=== ERROR === prediction p: NAN at index 0`

Or I get this message:

`[ WARN] [1441884003.214357239]: large time-gap re-initializing to last state`

And sometimes this:

`[ WARN] [1441884003.679369485]: Negative scale detected: -0.39217. Correcting to 0.1`

It is different depending on where the 'play head' is when I initialize.

I am running Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217554/ethzasl_sensor_fusion-only-works-first-time/) by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2015-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my case, you have to declare the variable q_wv in template_measurement.h. This should prevent you from getting nan.

---

Originally posted by [ssw1](https://answers.ros.org/users/25981/ssw1/) with karma: 16 on 2016-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0